# SPARC assembly Relocation Overflow when doing btst

Tags: assembly, sparc

When compiling the following code with gcc I get a Relocation Overflow error pointing to this line:

```
btst    0x8000, %l0
```

This is being compiled on a 32 bit machine so there should be no reason bit 15 (the 16th bit) should overflow a 32 bit register.

I have seen this pop up a few times with people trying to do and's and the accepted answer always seems to be "The most significant bit is bit 15 (in a 16-bit, when bits are zero based)" which I don't understand how that is relevant, when I want to access bit 15 and the bitmask to isolate bit 15 is 0x8000 is it not?

Thanks.

Comment: SPARC only supports 13-bit immediate operands.

Comment: The issue is that SPARC, like many RISC architecture, bakes its instructions into a fixed-length 32-bit instruction word. Therefore any immediate constants, addresses or the like needs to be squeezed into these same 32-bits, together the opcode and register number. The SPARC designers chose to allocate 13-bits for signed immediates, and so you may use constants between -4096 and +4095.

Comment: So what would be the correct approach to access the 15th bit?

Comment: @Nodnarb3: Use the `set` pseudo-instruction (letting the assembler piece together long values for you arithmetically) to load the required constant into a temporary register, and then use that in `btst` in place of the wide value.